# Can i install Hyper-v on a Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2008 or 2012?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I need to install Hyper-V on a Virtual Machine to have different OS to try my programs.My Virtual Machine is Windows Server 2008 R2 but if i need to i could change it to 2012.Could you explane it relatively simply because i'm not an expert.

Comment: This entirely depends if your hardware supports the required x86 extensions and hardware virtualization required to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is to run a "nested VM".  I suggest you use this term often when Googling for a solution.  Nested VMs are usually not particularly straight-forward, and a highly-dependent on several things specific to your configuration - physical hardware, virtual hardware, OS, virtualization softwares, etc.  You might imagine that running a 64-bit VM on a 32-bit hardware platform can cause problems that are "challenging" to overcome.

Here's VMWare's thoughts on [nesting VMs](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970).

Depending on what kind of VM you're running, and what kind of Hyper-v you want to run, you should look for configuration-specific instructions.